# How can i redirect user base on cookie, i faced many redirect using php

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, header

I am working using cookie. My client wants when a visitor visits his site, it will be automatically checked that he visited this site before.If he visited this site before, he will be auto redirected the site he visited before. If he doesn't visited this site before, cookie will be saved that if he will visited this site in future, he will be redirected his last visited page. For example, A site has many category or topic such as Food, Cloth etc. If a visitor visits this site in Cloth topic or category, cookie will be saved. Next time he visits this site, he will be automatically redirected cloth category page cause in past, he visited that page. But this time, a option in footer to save cookie again and if he click to accept cookie, cookie will be saved updated. 
Now i am trying to do this in localhost and shared it's file. Please check what's the problem or where. Here i use redirect option in header.php and face problem. If i use redirect option in index.php, error occurs ( see screenshot). If i use in header.php, error occurs in every page. See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/cbkux6
You can visit this site for an example: http://www.louisvuitton.com/

my header page

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['saveexperice'])){

    $link = $_COOKIE['saveexperice'];
    header("Location: $link");
    exit;
}
else{
    header('Location: http://localhost/cookie');
    $exlink = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    setcookie('saveexperice', $exlink, time()+60*60*24*30);
    exit;
}
```

My Index page

```
<?php 
include("header.php");

//$page_link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

echo "Index page";

//echo $page_link;

print_r($_COOKIE);




include("footer.php");
```

footer page

```
<a href="clearcooke.php">Logout</a>
```

Another page

```
<?php 
include("header.php");

print_r($_COOKIE);



echo "Ex php page";


include("footer.php");
```

cookie clear page

```
<?php 

$exlink = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

setcookie('saveexperice', $exlink, time()-60*60*24*30);

header('location: index.php');
```

another page

```
<?php 
include("header.php");



print_r($_COOKIE);



echo "CK php page";


include("footer.php");
```

You can download this full project zip file

http://www116.zippyshare.com/d/6Gz32nO0/2541183/Coockie.zip

Comment: Your header has no way to match if you are on the page that the header is forwarding to so it keeps redirecting. You have to have an `if` in the header that matches where you are and if you are not in the place you are supposed to be then it redirects you and if you are in the right place it doesn't redirect.

Comment: another page code pastebin.com/yjFmt3eg home page pastebin.com/k7RH0JQu

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, incase I wasn't clear, you don't have any stop code so either way, you will redirect. You have no condition where you will not redirect:

```
<?php
// Move here
$exlink = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

if(isset($_COOKIE['saveexperice'])){
    $link = $_COOKIE['saveexperice'];
    // If your cookie doesn't match where you are now
    if($exlink != $link) {
        // Redirect
        // NOTE: You may want to check the timestamp and only redirect
        // if the cookie is X-amount of minutes old otherwise you
        // will probably be stuck in another loop, always pushing you
        // to the same page.
        // If it's within the timeframe to not push to another page,
        // then you have to reset the cookie to the current page.
        header("Location: {$link}");
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    setcookie('saveexperice', $exlink, time()+60*60*24*30);
    // I am not sure why you need to redirect here since you are on a page
    // you supposedly want to be on
    header('Location: http://localhost/cookie');
    exit;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, so since you can not get my edit to work, I have added another layer to this to add some human-readable methods so the code is more understandable. IT is a quick class that you can build on, but all the methods are pretty self-explanatory. It's parts (in general) from one I use:

```
<?php
# I am calling it Session, but that is because it would have both cookie and session methods
class Session
    {
        private $expireTime,
                $cookieName;
        /*
        ** @description This will set the time for the cookie to expire
        */
        public  function setTime($time)
            {
                $this->expireTime   =   $time;
                return $this;
            }
        /*
        ** @description Returns the name of the last cookie used in the instance
        */
        public  function getName()
            {
                return $this->cookieName;
            }
        /*
        ** @description This will set the name of the cookie
        */
        public  function setName($name = false)
            {
                $this->cookieName   =   $name;
                return $this;
            }
        /*
        ** @description This actually creates the cookie
        */
        public  function setCookie($val, $name = false)
            {
                if(!empty($name))
                    $this->setName($name);

                if(empty($this->cookieName))
                    return false;

                $this->expireTime   =   (!empty($this->expireTime))? $this->expireTime : (time()+60*60*24*30);
                setcookie($this->cookieName,json_encode(array($this->expireTime,$val)),$this->expireTime);
            }
        /*
        ** @description Self-explanatory
        */
        public  function destroyCookie($name = false)
            {
                if(!empty($name))
                    $this->setName($name);

                if($this->cookieExists($this->cookieName))
                    setcookie($this->cookieName,null,(time()-1000));
            }
        /*
        ** @description Self-explanatory
        */
        public  function cookieExists($name = false)
            {
                if(!empty($name))
                    $this->setName($name);

                return (isset($_COOKIE[$this->cookieName]));
            }
        /*
        ** @description Self-explanatory
        */
        public  function getCookie($name = false)
            {
                $cookie =   $this->getCookieData($name);

                return (!empty($cookie[1]))? $cookie[1] : $cookie;
            }
        /*
        ** @description This will get an array of the value and expire time
        */
        public  function getCookieData($name = false)
            {
                if(!empty($name))
                    $this->setName($name);

                return (!empty($_COOKIE[$this->cookieName]))? json_decode($_COOKIE[$this->cookieName],true) : false;
            }
        /*
        ** @description Checks if the cookie is expired
        */
        public  function isExpired($name = false)
            {
                $cookie =   $this->getCookieData($name);
                if(!empty($cookie[0]))
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
        /*
        ** @description Gives an array for a countdown of sorts
        */
        public  function willExpire($name = false)
            {
                $cookie =   $this->getCookieData($name);
                $now    =   strtotime("now");
                if(!empty($cookie[0])) {
                    $seconds    =   ($now - $cookie[0]);
                    return  array(
                                'h'=>trim(number_format(($seconds/60/60),0),'-'),
                                'm'=>trim(number_format(($seconds/60),0),'-'),
                                's'=>trim($seconds,'-')
                            );
                }

                return true;
            }
        /*
        ** @description Resets the expire time on the cookie
        */
        public  function extendTime($time,$name=false)
            {
                $cookie =   $this->getCookieData($name);
                $this->setTime($time)->setCookie($cookie[1]);
            }
    }
```

To use:

```
<?php
# Add the class
require_once(__DIR__.'/Session.php');
# Create instance
$cEngine    =   new Session();
# Check if the cookie exists already
if(!$cEngine->cookieExists('saveexperice')) {
    # If it doesn't exist, create it by
    # First setting an expire time
    $cEngine->setTime(strtotime('now + 20 minutes'))
            # Add the data
            ->setCookie($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'saveexperice');
}
# This would just echo the value
echo $cEngine->getCookie();
# This will tell you when it will expire (count down)
print_r($cEngine->willExpire());
# This will extend the expiration time on the cookie
$cEngine->extendTime(strtotime("now + 1 day"));
# This will destroy the cookie
# $cEngine->destroyCookie();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I was use this code on my localhost then it's worked, but when i used this code on website then not working on website. Cookie doesn't save, i was echo cookie in body content but don't echo that.


how can i solve it? can you help me?

another page code
http://pastebin.com/yjFmt3eg

home page
http://pastebin.com/k7RH0JQu

Comment: Alright I added a class with some human-readable methods. It will hopefully make your setting of cookies easier to map out.

Comment: I have new post for need help related with this post, please you can see and can you help me that ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256311/cookie-is-working-fine-in-root-directory-but-not-working-sub-directory

Comment: Hi, This cookie doesn't work in sub directory, i can i use sub directory ?

Comment: It may have issues in sub domains (which you should be able to specify when making the cookie) but I don't see how a sub directory should have a problem accessing the cookie