# cookie is working fine in root directory but not working sub directory

Tags: php, cookies

I want when a visitor visit my site, then it will check that this site cookie is saved in his browser before. If doesn't it saved before, then new cookie will be saved. Then if he will visit home page, he will be redirected the page which was saved in his browser cookie. To do this, i use this code in any page:

```
$exlink =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

if(!isset($_COOKIE['saveexperice'])){
    setcookie('saveexperice', $exlink, time()+60*60*24*30, '/');
}
```

and use this code in home page:

```
if($_COOKIE['saveexperice']){
    $exlinkr = $_COOKIE['saveexperice'];
     header('Location: ' . $exlinkr);   
}
```

It's working fine. But problem is that it's only working on root directory. not working any sub directory such as domain.com/subfolder.
Here cookie will be made when a visitor visit, But if he visit home page, It won't redirected the subfolder. If i visit root directory any page such as domian.com/about.php, cookie will be saved and return my home page, it's redirected me to my saved cookie page as domain.com/about.php.
I want it's need to work in subfolder page.
How can i do this?

Comment: Because you're only setting the cookie __if__ it wasn't already set according to your code. `if(!isset($_COOKIE['saveexperice'])) {`

Comment: Yes, I have used that, i need to set cookie only if already not set cookie, now cookie are not problem, now problem is i can't use cookie main domian (root directory) from sub directory.

Comment: Now I have solution https://github.com/hmbashar/set-cookie-and-redirect-previous-visit-link-using-cookie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everyone, I got solution for that issue, If you need you can check github link

### Set cookie and redirect previous visit link using cookie

You can set cookie on visitor/client browser then when a visitor goes offline and again come back into your website then the visitor/client auto redirect last visit link when he tries visitor home page. He/she can't visit home page auto redirect latest link. He/she can again visit the home page after clear/delete the cookie.

Set Cookie
First you need to set link on browse as a cookie. just using below code.

```
$exlink =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
setcookie('saveexperice', $exlink, time()+(60*60*24*30), '/'); // set cookie for 30 days
```

Note: Must you need php file. like .php, if your file is .html, .css that php is not work (exmple for new user). and must using that code into header of above all code. example see screenshot http://prntscr.com/i7y64e

[image]

Now we've set last visited link on browser as a cookie

Now we'll get that url from cookie.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['last_visited_url'])){
    $redirect_url = $_COOKIE['last_visited_url'];       
}
```

Now we've got that url, and you can redirect header() to that url

```
header('Location: '. $redirect_url);
```

full code like

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['last_visited_url'])){
    $redirect_url = $_COOKIE['last_visited_url']; // get link from cookie
    header('Location: '. $redirect_url); // redirect cookie link
}
```

Note: Must you need php file. like .php, if your file is .html, .css that php is not work (exmple for new user). and must using that code into header of above all code. example see screenshot http://prntscr.com/i7y8km

[image]

just set cookie for another page and place redirect code Which link will be redirected by visiting? like home page.

Cookie clear/delete
Now you can remove/clear your cookie using that code

```
$cookieurl =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

setcookie('last_visited_url', $current_location, time()-60*60*24*30, '/'); // remove cookie time

header('location: https://link.com'); // inpur link which link redirect after clear cookie
```

[image]

Change Cookie link

```
$current_location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(isset($_COOKIE['last_visited_url'])){
 $cookie_location = $_COOKIE['last_visited_url']; 


 if($current_location != $cookie_location){ 

    setcookie('last_visited_url', $current_location, time()+60*60*24*30, '/'); 
 } 
} else {
 setcookie('last_visited_url', $current_location, time()+60*60*24*30, '/'); 
}
```

[Check Here on github](https://github.com/hmbashar/set-cookie-and-redirect-previous-visit-link-using-cookie)